# Chain two request and return the first one

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a class `A` like this:

```
A {
   id: Long
   eventId: Long
   event: Event
}

B{
   id:Long
   name: String
}
```

I want to retrieve A by executing:

```
aService.getA(id)
```

then with the result (which has a `null` event) use `eventId` to retrieve the proper `Event` (`eventService.getEvent()`), assign it to `A.event`, and then return `A`.

How can I chain the request to achieve this? I tried flatmap to return the `Event` but then I lose the result from `A`.

This is my current implementation:

```
aRepository.getA().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .doOnSubscribe {
                            loadingState.onNext(true)
                        }
                        .doOnEvent { t1: Highlight, t2 ->
                            loadingState.onNext(false)
                        }
                        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<A>() {
                            override fun onSuccess(a: A) {
                                aObservable.onNext(a)
                            }

                            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                               fetchErrors.onNext(e)
                            }

                        })
```

I tried this:

```
aRepository.getA()
                   .flatMap {
                        a: A ->
                        val event = eventsRepository.getEvent(a.eventId)
                        event
                    }
                        ,subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .doOnSubscribe {
                            loadingState.onNext(true)
                        }
                        .doOnEvent { t1: Highlight, t2 ->
                            loadingState.onNext(false)
                        }
                        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<A>() {
                            override fun onSuccess(a: A) {
                                aObservable.onNext(a)
                            }

                            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                               fetchErrors.onNext(e)
                            }

                        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap` and just map its inner flow back to the updated original value:

```
aRepository.getA()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap(a -> {
    if (a.event == null) {
        return eventsRepository.getEvent(a.eventId)
               .map(evt -> {
                   a.event = evt;
                   return a;
               });
    }
    return Single.just(a);
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeWith(/* ... */)
;
```